# What parts are required to convert a bicycle to a front-wheel drive e-bike?

Tags: parts, electric-bike, conversion

My stepfather purchased a electrically driven front wheel hub. He has asked me to purchase all of the remaining parts required to convert his bicycle to an e-bike with this hub. He resides in Virginia and I live in Georgia.

Besides the battery, what other parts would be required to complete this bicycle-to-e-bike conversion?

Comment: Convert bike from what to what?  Are you meaning convert a standard mounting bike to a front wheel drive e-bike?

Comment: Why are you yelling?  Is your caps lock key stuck?  Did you read your question to see if it makes sense?  What conversion are you talking about?  Why not put that in the first sentence?

Comment: Ask the rider for some clear photos of what they have.  Photos of connectors from the side and end, and photos of any labels.  Model numbers are also useful.

Comment: Also consider the front wheel is generally easily removed - could be someone has fenced a wheel stolen from someone's bike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many suppliers offer kits, with parts lists - e.g.
(from https://dillengerelectricbikes.co.nz/collections/street-legal-kits/products/street-legal-electric-bike-kit-samsung-powered-v2)

- Motorwheel
- Battery
- Controller / Battery Cradle
- Battery Charger
- LCD Handlebar Display with control panel
- Thumb Throttle
- RPAS (Removeable pedal assist sensor)
- E-Brake Sensors
- 4 to 1 Wiring Harness
- Motor Extension Cable
- Plastic Wiring Loom/Sleeve
- Cable Ties (10)
- "C" Washers (2)

What you need, and what they supply might be different, and the exact parts will depend on the motor and need to be compatible.

Frankly, unless you know exactly what you are doing, or are prepared to to an awful lot of homework, you will likely save time and money buying a kit and not using the front wheel he already bought. You may be able to find a kit supplier who sells can supply the parts you need to drive the wheel he has.

You probably want to check any local regulations - e.g. https://www.peopleforbikes.org/electric-bikes/state-laws